# How to define a template in a looser way than interfaces in C#

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Say I have a group of classes which generate documents from templates. For example...

```
class CustomerInvoice
{
    public satic string TemplatePath 
    { 
        get { return @"C:\Templates\InvoiceTemplate.doc"; }
    }

    public static DocumentType DocumentType 
    { 
        get { return DocumentType.WordDocument; }
    }

    public static void Create(Customer customer, int orderNumber)
    {
         //...
    }
}
```

All of these classes share the same method *names*, but not necessarily method *signatures*.

For example, I might have

```
CustomerInvoice.Create(Customer customer, int orderNumber);
DespatchNote.Create(Customer customer, int orderNumber, Warehouse warehouse);
PackingLabel.Create(int orderNumber);
```

... or whatever (struggling to come up with sensible examples).

Is there a mechanism in OO which specifies what method names a group of classes has in this way? I'm really thinking of just having a way to enforce consistent implementation and naming accross a group of similar objects, so they are more intuitive for consumers. Would a case like this be considered a valid/worthwhile use of any such technique?

Comment: You can use reflection check your types for certain rules. But if possible I'd the generics based solution Marc suggested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no construct for that. Static methods *in particular* have no way of enforcing any commonality. If is was an interface you could have something like `Create(object)` or `Create(T)` (for some T defined on a generic interface) and take a single parameter to represent te state.

Answer (score 2):

> consistent implementation and naming accross a group of similar objects, so they are more intuitive for consumers

Since you're talking about ensuring the *public* interface of your API conforms to a certain system, I don't think there are necessarily going to be any OOP constructs that will help.

What might help however is any one of a number of tools intended to control *style* and *design*. I'm thinking of things like StyleCop, FxCop, and NDepend, all of which allow the creation of custom rules (with varying amounts of pain!). In particular, NDepend would allow you to set up a Code Query Language rule along the lines of

```
WARN IF Count == 0 IN SELECT METHODS WHERE NameIs "Create" AND IsStatic
```

which (applied to a suitable namespace) would warn if any particular class did not have a static method (of any signature) named `Create`